# Dockerfile entrypoint

Tags: docker, cron, containers, sh, dockerfile

I'm trying to customize the docker image presented in the following repository 
https://github.com/erkules/codership-images

I created a cron job in the Dockerfile and tried to run it with CMD, knowing the Dockerfile for the erkules image has an ENTRYPOINT `["/entrypoint.sh"]`. It didn't work.

I tried to create a separate cron-entrypoint.sh and add it into the dockerfile, then test something like this ENTRYPOINT `["/entrypoint.sh", "/cron-entrypoint.sh"]`. But also get an error.

I tried to add the cron job to the entrypoint.sh of erkules image, when I put it at the beginning, then the container runs the cron job but doesn't execute the rest of the entrypoint.sh. And when I put the cron script at the end of the entrypoint.sh, the cron job doesn't run but anything above in the entrypoint.sh gets executed.

How can I be able to run what's in the the entrypoint.sh of erkules image and my cron job at the same time through the Dockerfile?

Comment: Should it be ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]?

Comment: Add `crond` at some point to the entrypoint.sh

Comment: not necessary...as long as I can run both the entrypoint.sh and the cron job

Comment: I tried to add cron -f to the the entrypoint.sh but like  I said if it's at the beginning nothing else gets executed if It's an the end, the cron doesn't get executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the cron command to background, so either use `&` or remove the `-f` (`-f  means: Stay in foreground mode, don't daemonize.`)

So, in your entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cron -f &
(
 # the other commands here
)
```

---

Edit: I am totally agree with @BMitch regarding the way that you should handle multiple processes, but inside the same container, which is something not so recommended.

See examples here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to look at is whether you need multiple applications running in the same container. Ideally, the container would only run a single application. You may be able to run multiple containers for different apps and connect them together with the same networks or share a volume to achieve your goals.

Assuming your design requires multiple apps in the same container, you can launch some in the background and run the last in the foreground. However, I would lean towards using a tool that manages multiple processes. Two tools I can think of off the top of my head are supervisord and foreman in go. The advantage of using something like supervisord is that it will handle signals to shutdown the applications cleanly and if one process dies, you can configure it to automatically restart that app or consider the container failed and abend.